# Format Hyperlink Column in SharePoint to highlight empty fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, hyperlink, json-formatting

I'm new to JSON column formatting and fairly sure this has been asked before or at least covered, but I'm trying to find a way to highlight empty fields in the SharePoint column (hyperlink) to display a yellow or red background with possibly some text 'Link Required'.

Is there a simple way to do this in the JSON formatting? i.e. IF empty show text 'Link Required' plus a red background ELSE show value in the column.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using SharePoint JSON column formatting. Try using below JSON on your hyperlink column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "Link Required",
      "style": {
        "background-color": "yellow",
        "display": "=if(@currentField, 'none', 'block')",
        "padding": "5px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "@currentField.desc",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "@currentField"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(@currentField, 'block', 'none')"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

You can modify this JSON as per your requirements to change the background color from yellow to red OR to change any other styling properties.

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: That's great, works perfectly. Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction!